# Copy file progress in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, progress-bar

The following script copies files from one location to another, in reality there will be a lot of files to copy. What would be the best way to show the progress of the copy command whilst it is running? i.e. if it is still working its way through, it has failed or completed.

```cs
$from = "C:\Sites\T"
$to = "C:\Customer\"
$exclude = @("Aeromark")
$excludeMatch = @("Aeromark")
$StartDate = (Get-Date).AddYears(-2)
$EndDate = Get-Date

[regex]$excludeMatchRegEx = ‘(?i)‘ + (($excludeMatch | foreach {[regex]::Escape($_)}) –join “|”) + ‘’
Get-ChildItem -Path $from -Recurse -Exclude $exclude | where {
    $excludeMatch -eq $null -or
    $_.FullName.Replace($from, "") -notmatch $excludeMatchRegEx -and
    ($_.CreationTime.Date -ge $StartDate.Date) -and
    ($_.CreationTime.Date -le $EndDate.Date)
} | Copy-Item -Destination {
    if ($_.PSIsContainer) {
        Join-Path $to $_.Parent.FullName.Substring($from.Length)
    } else {
        Join-Path $to $_.FullName.Substring($from.Length)
    }
} -Force -Exclude $exclude -Verbose *> c:\temp\log_sites_customer_excluding_aeromark_copy.txt
```

Comment: So You really have 2 separate questions. 1) how to show progress. this can be done using `Write-Progress` command. 
2) how to see if the command failed to copy any file - You could use try-catch and parse errors

Comment: Have you considered using [Robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) instead?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-progress?view=powershell-6  write-progress cmdlet.  You would have to get the full list of file names to copy first, then update the progress bar as each one finishes.